# Find the value of $p$ for which $f^{'\:}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\:=\:g^{'\:}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that $f\left(x\right)\:=\:tan^{-1}\left(2x\right)$ and $g\left(x\right)\:=\:p\:tan^{-1}\left(x\right),$ where $p$ is a constant. Find the value of $p$ for which $f^{'\:}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\:=\:g^{'\:}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's find:

- $$\frac{\text{d}\text{f}\left(x\right)}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\arctan\left(2x\right)\right)=\frac{2}{1+4x^2}\tag1$$
- $$\frac{\partial\text{g}\left(x\right)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\text{p}\arctan\left(x\right)\right)=\text{p}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\arctan\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{\text{p}}{1+x^2}\tag2$$

So, we have:

$$\frac{2}{1+4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{\text{p}}{1+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{p}=\frac{5}{4}\tag3$$